# Convert formatted log string back to LogRecord

Tags: python

What is the best way to convert a log string back to the `LogRecord` that caused that string to be generated in the first place, provided that I have the formatter string.

I know I can use regex for this, but I was wondering if there's a better way to achieve this.

**Formatter**:

```
%(asctime)s--%(name)s--%(levelname)s--%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s---%(message)s
```

**Sample**:

```
2014-07-28 16:46:39,221--sys.log--DEBUG--hello:61---hello world
```

**Regex**:

```
^(?P<asctime>.*?)--(?P<name>.*?)--(?P<levelname>.*?)--(?P<funcName>.*?):(?P<lineno>.*?)---(?P<message>.*?)$
```

**Regex example**:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('^(?P<asctime>.*?)--(?P<name>.*?)--(?P<levelname>.*?)--(?P<funcName>.*?):(?P<lineno>.*?)---(?P<message>.*?)$')
print pattern.match('2014-07-28 16:46:39,221--sys.log--DEBUG--hello:61---hello world').groupdict()
```

**Output**:

```
{'name': 'sys.log', 'funcName': 'hello', 'lineno': '61', 'asctime': '2014-07-2816:46:39,221', 'message': 'hello world', 'levelname': 'DEBUG'}
```

**References**:

1. https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html
2. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` sign or the `:`.

Comment: `re.escape` seems to think I do, escaped this using that before replacing this with the named groups. I'm aware of the significance of your comment, the `-` means nothing outside the `[]` but why does `re.escape` escape it as it does?

Comment: These are the only metacharacters which need to be escaped: `. ^ $ * + ? { } [ ] \ | ( )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this example, just split at the double-dashes:

```
sample = '2014-07-28 16:46:39,221--sys.log--DEBUG--hello:61---hello world'
fields = ('asctime', 'name', 'levelname', 'funcName', 'message')
values = { k: v for k, v in zip(fields, sample.split('--', len(fields) - 1)) }
# and do some mending
values['funcName'], values['lineno'] = values['funcName'].split(':')
values['message'] = values['message'][1:]
```

```
>>> values
{'asctime': '2014-07-28 16:46:39,221',
 'funcName': 'hello',
 'levelname': 'DEBUG',
 'lineno': '61',
 'message': 'hello world',
 'name': 'sys.log'}
```